# If String is an object, but unlike Array(which is also an object), why can we directly print out its value?

Tags: java, arrays, string, reference, heap-memory

I am confuse about how it works in memory. For objects, the variable should contains a reference to the object. Therefore, when it is printed, it will print out the address containing the object. This is in the case of Array. I understand String Literal vs String Object. String literal --- > common pool. But i am just confuse about how it works in memory. Technically the string variable should hold a reference to the string object.

Comment: The `String` variable **is** just a reference to a `String` instance. Same as every other `Object` type. `String` *overrides* `Object.toString()`. `Array` does not.

Answer (score 0):

I supose that is because of the toString method, with is accessed when you try to print any object.